# How to exclude my sub domain from redirect http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

After some twerking I have managed to redirect my site from http to https, as well as other redirects. Glad it works, but there is only one problem! My subdomain pages redirect to the domain home page. I have tried various exclusion methods, but I can't crack it. I would appreciate you help! 
(Would like to run the blog in https as well.)

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ https://www.westhavenretreat.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.westhavenretreat.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.(.*)\. [NC]
```